# Problem with deploy react app on azure web app

Tags: reactjs, azure

I've created a simple React.js application, but I'm having trouble deploying it to Azure. I've set up a Web App with Node on Azure, and I'm using Visual Studio Code to upload the application. From the FTP perspective, I can see that the files have been uploaded. Unfortunately, the link to the application keeps displaying the default page.

Interestingly, when I choose the option "site wwwroot" in SCM, the page displays correctly. I would appreciate any advice you may have.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi @Dorian Daszkiewicz Can you share the code and also Check all the necessary files, especially the index.html and the contents of the build folder, are correctly deployed to the Azure Web App.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `npm run build`, check the build output is being copied to the correct directory. The default output directory for React App is the `build` folder.

[image]

- Here, I created a react application and deployed to the Azure app service and its running successfully. Before that I have added below configuration to my application.

**Package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "react-scripts build"
}
```

After the deployment, Check whether all files are deployed successfully.

[image]

**Note:** I have deployed through FTP from the Visual studio code Editor.

[image]